# feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-selection

I have document-term data with terms as dimensions. I have to perform feature selection on the terms and I intend to use Mutual Information as the measure to perform feature selection. My doubt here is that after calculating the mutual information between all possible pairs what is to be done?
Should I set a threshold and select all the terms of the pairs that fall within the threshold?

Comment: Yes, this is what would be done usually.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff Can you tell us on what basis we can decide on the threshold?

Comment: Depends on your specific data and how many features you want to keep. Ideally, you would notice a sudden and significant change from almost no mutual information to a lot of mutual information which would tell you where to put your threshold. In practice this may not be the case though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use mutual information you can consider to use mRMR algrorithm. You can select features with such kind of algorithms. What I mean:

```
You have n features at your data set (it means n dimensions)
```

If you want to use most meaningful

```
k of n (k < n)
```

You can use feature selection (i.e. with mRMR that uses mutual information background)

Deciding on *k* depends on some situations.

- One of them is you don't want to use unnecessary features at your
  model creation.
- Other thing is you want to aviod calculation cost and remove some
  features from your data set

You should test your algorithm after you removed some features. You examine that does accuracy goes up and depending on your aim even accuracy goes down does it resulting with avoiding from calculation cost(so you may want to eleminate some features too)

On the other hand I suggest you to look at feature extraction methods i.e. PCA and also LDA (especially for your case).

Comment: mRMR needs classes to be known before hand (supervised). What kind of methods should be used for feature selection when class labels are not known?